# How to make Crystal Report print directly to printer without exporting to PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, printing, crystal-reports

I have a web application in Asp.net which is using Crystal Reports and I am using CrystalReportViewer to show crystal report on my aspx page.
When I click on Print Button to Print it show me Message

The viewer must export to PDF to print. Choose the Print option from the PDF reader application once the document is opened. Note: You must have a PDF reader installed to print. (eg. Adobe Reader)

It doesn't Print my report directly .
Please help.....

Comment: Most of the modern browsers will support pdf,you dont need a pdf reader to be installed to open a pdf file.

Comment: I have installed pdf reader(adobe reader) also but I don't want to Export to  pdf first. I want to print direct on print button

Comment: hello @satyender if you have any solution please help me. i have same problem. see this link My Que. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058712/how-to-remove-print-to-pdf-box-when-click-on-print-button-on-crystal-report

Comment: Hello satyender. Did you find a solution for this? I'm also having the same issue.

Comment: no dear i removed crystal report and design html with css and directly print that div

Answer (score 8):

Crystal report has  **[PrintToPrinter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** method to print report direct to printer.

like this

```
crystalReportDocument.Load("your crystal report file path");
crystalReportDocument.SetDataSource("report data source");
crystalReportDocument.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "your printer name"
crystalReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0);
```

Comment: please add source code to your question, which you are using  .

Comment: I couldn't find PrinterName property of PrintOptions