# Remove option to Print to PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

When clicking the print button for my Crystal report, I see this:

[image]

I don't want to Export to PDF first, I just want to print immediately when the Print button is pushed. How can I configure this behavior?

Comment: Hello Pratik, did you find a solution for this? I'm also having the same issue.
When I click the print button, I'm expecting the print window ( just to select the printer and page size, etc) But it gives the same screen as you mentioned above.

Comment: @AnuraAdhikari NO

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use the `PrintToPrinter` method. According to MSDN:

> Prints the specified pages of the report to the printer selected using the PrintOptions.PrinterName property. If no printer is selected, the default printer specified in the report will be used.

You'll need to pass the number of copies, whether or not it should be coallated, and the start/end pages as parameters. Something like:

```
public void PrintToPrinter (5, false, 1, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks @4444 But when i am use PrintToPrinter it's Direct Print When Report Load. I just want to print immediately when the Print button is Clicked